# Combine two values in two separate SQL tables

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have two SQL tables as below:

```
tblparts
----------------------------
Part          Quantity
----------------------------
AAA1000       1
AAB1000       2
AAC1000       3
```

And the second named 'tblestparts':

```
tblestparts
----------------------------
ID      Part          Quantity
----------------------------
1       AAA1000       20
1       AAB1000       21
1       AAC1000       22
2       AAA1000       15
```

I want to add the quantity of part AAA1000 shown in tblestparts to the quantity shown in tblparts, where the ID in tblestparts = 1, and update the quantity figure for part AAA1000 in tblparts to that combined number.

So the outcome would be that tblparts now looks like this:

```
tblparts
----------------------------
Part          Quantity
----------------------------
AAA1000       21
AAB1000       2
AAC1000       3
```

I've given this a few goes, and have come up with the following, but alas it doesn't work and I don't know where I'm going wrong?

```
UPDATE tblparts SET tblparts.Quantity = tblparts.Quantity + tblestparts.Quantity FROM tblparts INNER JOIN tblestparts ON tblestparts.Part = tblparts.Part WHERE tblparts.Part = 'AAA1000' AND tblestparts.ID = 1
```

Thanks for any advice in advance!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you might want to read [Is adding the ‘tbl’ prefix to table names really a problem?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/)

Answer (score 1):

In many databases, a correlated subquery might work. Assuming that there is always a match in the source table:

```
update tblparts p
set quantity = quantity + (select e.quantity from tblestparts e where e.part = p.part)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works:

`UPDATE tblparts p SET Quantity = Quantity + (SELECT e.Quantity from tblestparts e WHERE e.Part = p.Part AND p.Part = 'AAA1000' AND e.ID = '1')`

However, to complicate things a little, if I need to update several part numbers (held in an array) all on the same ID number, I have tried the following, but it doesn't do anything?

`UPDATE tblparts p SET Quantity = Quantity + (SELECT e.Quantity from tblestparts e WHERE e.Part = p.Part AND p.Part IN ('AAA1000,AAB1000') AND e.ID = '1')`

I really appreciate all of your kind attention and help from all of you with this.

Comment: @nb86: it is far better to pass parameters separatly: `... p.part IN ('AAA1000','AAB1000') AND ...`

Comment: I have now discovered one slight issue, if you run the statement with an ID number which doesn't exist in the 'tblestparts' table, say '3', for some reason it sets every single Quantity value in the 'tblparts' table to zero?

Comment: In fact it's worse than that, it is setting the Quantity in tblparts to 0 for every part which isn't in the IN array too?

Answer (score 1):

When you say doesn't work, what do you mean?  Assuming it is `SQL Server` - `T-SQL`, then what you are doing looks correct.

So to convert your scenario to use table variables, hence the `@` prefix on the table names - ie this is a variable, then the following gives you what you want:

### setup

```
declare @tblparts table
(
      part varchar(100)
    , quantity int
);

declare @tblestparts table
(
      id int
    , part varchar(100)
    , quantity int
);

insert into @tblparts
values 
('AAA1000', 1),
('AAB1000', 2),
('AAC1000', 3)

insert into @tblestparts
values
(1,       'AAA1000',       20),
(1,       'AAB1000',       21),
(1,       'AAC1000',       22),
(2,       'AAA1000',       15)
```

### update

```
UPDATE t 
SET t.Quantity = t.Quantity + st.Quantity 
FROM @tblparts t 
INNER JOIN @tblestparts st ON st.Part = t.Part 
WHERE t.Part = 'AAA1000' AND st.ID = 1
```

All I've done here is changed your query to use aliases for simplicity.  Additionally you don't need `AND st.ID = 1` here.

### result

The following query:

```
select *
from @tblparts
```

yields the following results:

```
AAA1000 21  
AAB1000 2  
AAC1000 3
```

The thing is with your query, you can only run it once before you lose the initial data from the update.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help :)